# JSON strange synchronized in source code

Tags: java, json, synchronization, jetty

I've found such a strange code in JSON class of jetty-util in org.mortbay.util.ajax package, and wondering whether it is an error or not.
My only guess is to read `_deafult` variable from memory, share your thoughts guys!

```
public static String toString(Object object)
    {
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(__default.getStringBufferSize());
        synchronized (buffer)
        {
            __default.append(buffer,object);
            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does look entirely pointless - the `buffer` instance is constructed right there within the thread, so no other threads could possibly have a reference to it.  Hence the `synchronized` block will *always* be uncontended, and is thus not guarding anything, plus no other thread will synchronize on it later, so there are no memory consistency effects.

Depending on the intended semantics, this may be an error, or it may just be a quirk left over from refactoring that doesn't cause any problems.  (Since in terms of correctness it's equivalent to not synchronising at all, and in terms of performance it's only marginally worse.)

On the plus side, Hotspot in Java 6 will optimise this block away. :-)

Comment: I thought that this piece of code is needed to reread cached by current thread _default variable. What do you think?

Comment: @pls - well, it has no mutex effects because other threads cannot synchronize on the same monitor, and it has no memory consistency effects because again, other threads cannot synchronize on the same monitor.  Hence it won't do anything to do with the `_default` variable, though perhaps it was intended to and a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the odds are pretty high they meant to write `synchronized (__default)` instead of `synchronized (buffer)`. This would be to avoid allowing any changes to `__default` during the call to `append` (assuming they also synchronize on it elsewhere, when making changes, or that its mutator functions do — you haven't mentioned what `__default` is, not that it matters much). I can't see any reason at all for synchronizing on `buffer`.